# How to fix Download the Upgrade Compatibility Tool error?

Tags: magento2.4, magento2.4.2, magento2.4.3, magento2.4.1, magento2.4.4

i'm trying to  download the upgrade compatibility tool and tried it in downloading in **HTML** folder or any other project but always it gives the same error.
**Any idea**[image]

Answer (score 1):

This tool requires Adobe Commerce access keys, it is not available for Magento Opensource.

Comment: i got my access keys, whats the next step

Comment: you have to config your Adobe Commerce access key in the auth.json file, then run `composer create-project magento/upgrade-compatibility-tool uct --repository https://repo.magento.com`

Comment: auth.jason file path will be user\.config\composer\auth.jason?
right?

Comment: the path for **auth.json** is /home/<user>/.config/composer

Comment: thanks man, appreciate